# Tensorflow, obtain new tensor from existing one

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, tensor

I have a tensor of this shape: `[BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE]` and I need to use it as input to a layer of lstm cells. 
In order to do that I need a tensor of this shape: `[BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, INPUT_SIZE]` but I can't simply reshape my first tensor, because in that way I'd "break" the input size. Am I right?
How can I obtain the tensor I need?.

EDIT:
The tensor with shape `[BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE]` is the output of a maxpooling layer (after a reshape):

```
convo_2 = convolutional_layer(convo_1_pooling, shape=[5, 5, 32, 64])
convo_2_pooling = max_pool_2by2(convo_2)
conv_flat = tf.reshape(convo_2_pooling, shape=[-1, 64*25*50])
```

the `conv_flat` variable is the input the lstm layer.

Comment: Do you have time steps?

Comment: I think it can be any number, the problem is to obtain a new tensor. I suppose that reshape will break my original input size and that is wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: it depends on your data, what are you trying to model? what is the time dimension of your data?

Comment: for instance if you have a text, with sequences of words, time steps will be the amount of words in the order of appearance on the text

Comment: What is the output shape of `convo_2_pooling` without the reshaping? not sure that reshaping just to fit lstm input will help you, first you need to understand your data and see if it makes sense for it to have the time dimension. Reshaping to [BATCH_SIZE, 1, INPUT_SIZE] is possible, but then you don't need the lstm.

Comment: another option is that instead of reshaping to [-1, 64*25*50], you reshape to [-1, 64*25, 50], then transpose the dimensions so that the `50` is the timestep (`tf.transpose(reshaped_input, perm=[0, 2, 1])`)

Comment: convo_2_pooling output should be [n_batches, 64,50,25]. I tried what you suggests, but the output I got an error because the number of batches of the output of the lstm layer is different from the real one (greater).

Comment: Usually lstms have an output per timestep, depending on what you want you use them all, or just the last one.